# Geo field proximity distance for exact location

Tags: search, location

I'm tried this for a day,but i won't get the answers. I'm using geo field proximity for zip code searching, it's working with 5,25,30 miles search, but i want to search exact location of zip code.

eg
    In search zip code : 73301, all the record in 73301 will be show.

Answer (score 0):

Zip codes don't have exact location. A zip code is an area in which the coordinates are a point within it. In most cases it is probably the centroid.

Comment: how can get the result of excat zip code match... any option / method that would help for me.. please advice

Comment: You can't.  [**Esri Data & Maps**](http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?owner=esri&title=ESRI%20Data%20%26%20Maps&content=all&q=zip&t=group) provide zip code areas you can search to find if location is in a specific area.